# Angular Bootstrap Modal Add Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an Angular application which contains a simple timer that resets on a `mousemove` event. So far I have been able to handle this by adding the `ng-mousemove` event to my outer most scope. However, when a Angular Bootstrap Modal appears, it is positioned in the DOM after that scope, so the event gets ignored until the modal is closed.

My current application is structured as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-ng-controller="shell as vm">
            <div ng-mousemove="vm.handleMouseMove()">
                ...
            </div>
            // MODAL APPEARS DOWN HERE
            <div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade ng-isolate-scope warning in" ...>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to:

a.) Add the `ng-mousemove` directive to the modal wrapper

or

b.) Move the modal into my scope, so that `shell` is a parent to the modal controller.

Comment: Are you sure? Non library or plugin add elements outside the body. Can you explain why do you need your _ng-mousemove_ event?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need that timer reset behaviour but you could do it like this.

Add your shell controller and `ng-mousemove` to the body-tag and style your body/html to fill the whole page with css `width: 100%; height:100%`.

Please have a look at the demo below and this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/cvfz3vwL/).

```js
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('shell', function($scope, $interval, $modal) {
    $scope.test = 'hello world';
    this.counter = 0;
    var vm = this;
    
    this.moveHandler = function() {
        console.log('mouse moved, reset counter!');
        vm.counter = 0;
    };
    
    var timer = function(iterCount) {
        console.log('timer tick', vm.counter);
        vm.counter++;
    };
    
    var intervalPromise = $interval(timer, 100);
    
    $scope.$on("$destroy", function handler() {
        // destruction code here
        $interval.cancel(intervalPromise); // stop interval on destroy of ctrl.
    });
    
     $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });
  };
});

// modal code from angular-ui-bootstrap demo
app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
});

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="wrapper" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="shell as vm" ng-mousemove="vm.moveHandler()">
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Large modal</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">Small modal</button>
    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>

{{test}}
</div>
</body>
```